# ava: Logs generated outside tests are not shown in the console

Tags: ava

## My problem

ava logging (`t.log`) only work inside a test, but not during setup (`before`, `beforeEach`) or teardown (`after*`) functions.

This means that meaningful setup / teardown data, which is very useful for debugging and reproducing, is lost. This happens both for successful and failed tests, and with and without the `--verbose` flag.

## Code

```
import test from 'ava';

test.before(t => {
    // This runs before all tests
    t.log('before - 1');
});

test.before(t => {
    // This runs after the above, but before tests
    t.log('before - 2');
});

test.after('cleanup', t => {
    // This runs after all tests
    t.log('after');
});

test.after.always('guaranteed cleanup', t => {
    // This will always run, regardless of earlier failures
    t.log('after always');
});

test.beforeEach(t => {
    // This runs before each test
    t.log('beforeEach');
});

test.afterEach(t => {
    // This runs after each test
    t.log('afterEach');
});

test.afterEach.always(t => {
    // This runs after each test and other test hooks, even if they failed
    t.log('afterEachAlways');
});

test(t => {
    t.log('A test');
    t.pass();
});


test(t => {
    t.log('A test');
    t.fail();
});
```

## Output

```
$ ava run.js --verbose

  ✔ [anonymous]
    ℹ A test
  ✖ [anonymous] Test failed via `t.fail()`
    ℹ A test

  1 test failed [00:22:08]

  [anonymous]
    ℹ A test

  /Users/adam/Personal/tmp/ava-bug-log-in-before-each/run.js:46

   45:     t.log('A test');
   46:     t.fail();
   47: });

  Test failed via `t.fail()`
```

Note that only the printouts from the test (`A test`) are show. All other logs are lost.

## My question

How can I see the logs from the setup and teardown steps of the test suite?

Comment: Notice that if you output straight to console.log the lines will be printed out. It's the ava logger that's acting weird here.

Comment: @AssafLavie True, but using `console.log` breaks our code guidelines (eslint with [airbnb style](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)) and I'd rather avoid the "ignore this line" instructions to the linter as they make the code less clean. Hope to find a simple workaround with `t.log`.

Comment: clearly. just noted. anyhow, it seems like an Ava deficiency. It's either not using the same execution context when you're calling `t.log` (you can test this, btw) or the log accumulation (there's some internal array it uses to push lines) gets reset when the test starts... I would open a bug.

Comment: @AssafLavie Already did (see the first answer by one of the maintainers https://stackoverflow.com/a/46400358/51197)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you open an issue for this? https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues

I agree this should work.

Comment: [With pleasure](https://github.com/avajs/ava/issues/1536), complete with [a separate git repo exemplifying the problem](https://github.com/adamatan/ava-logging-bug).